# Windows 8 versions

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between Windows 8 editions?](https://superuser.com/questions/402059/what-are-the-differences-between-windows-8-editions)

There are different versions of Windows 8, but I can't find info about them...
Does anyone knows what is Windows 8 Symbols?

[image]

Comment: Not an exact exact duplicate, but answers the question.

Comment: I only see two versions of Windows 8 in this screenshot.  A 64-bit version and a 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just the [Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) for Windows 8. You most likely won't need it.

The [debug/checked version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463171) is used for debugging device drivers. It contains run-time checks for error conditions and has run-time optimizations removed.

Source: [What are "Debug/Checked" versions of a Windows OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/397060/what-are-debug-checked-versions-of-a-windows-os)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.