# Can I use a Debug/Checked build of Windows 8 as an OS?

Tags: windows-8-preview

Simple question, is it possible to use the Debug/Checked build of Windows 8 as a primary OS?

What complications could arise from doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt that's a good idea. David Schwartz already noted that these builds lack [run-time checks for error conditions and run-time optimizations](https://superuser.com/a/397069/36744).

According to [Using Checked Builds of Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463171) the following changes were made in these builds:

> - Many compiler optimizations are disabled to make it easier to understand disassembled machine instructions and trace problems.
> - Many debugging checks are enabled to help identify internal inconsistencies and problems, including:
>
>   - Parameter validation checks
>   - Internal checks for operating system correctness and consistency
>   - Informational checks and tracing output, often documented in Microsoft Knowledge Base articles

So I would assume that there are noticeable performance penalties from using these builds in an every day environment. Possibly, instead of the usual "Do you want to report this issue?" dialog, you just get a BSOD. But I'm just guessing.

Personally, I'd advise against it.